# Using liquibase file paths via both maven and spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase

I update scheme and initial data in spring context using the following beean:

```
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml" />
    <property name="dropFirst" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I also use Maven liquibase plugin to generate sql scripts in order to see what tables are created and etc.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--mvn initialize liquibase:updateSQL-->
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/config/liquibase-gensql-data-access.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>

                </configuration>
           </plugin>
```

The `db.changelog-master.xml` file includes child liquibase changelog files. The problem, how to refer to them from the master. When I use Spring I have to use the following path via classpath:

```
<include file="classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
```

When Maven is used, the path is:

```
<include file="src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
```

I'd like to have the same configuration for both cases. How can I archive it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I commented on Igor's answer, his solution does not seem to work.

In order to solve this, I just pushed a patch to Liquibase: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/187. This should be merged in 3.0.6-SNAPSHOT and therefore shortly available in 3.0.6.

With this change, you can now configure `SpringLiquibase` with this additional line:

```
<property name="ignoringClasspathPrefix" value="true" />
```

Another example/usecase requiring this change can be found here: https://github.com/LateralThoughts/spring-liquibase-extensions.

Comment: Just an update: as of liquibase-3.1, the property is now called `ignoreClasspathPrefix` and is true by deault.

Comment: Small detail that made it work for me: in Maven, don't specify the `src/main/resources` part, otherwise it will be incompatible with Spring. I configured `db/changelog/...` in Maven, and `classpath:db/changelog/...` in Spring (application.properties) and then it worked.

Answer (score 11):

I think if you change your Maven path from

```
<changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
```

to

```
<changeLogFile>db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
```

and update db.changelog-master.xml file for all included files to use path relative to src/main/resources directory, it will fix the problem.

I solved this problem by using the same path to changeLog files in Spring, maven and integration test which call Liquibase. All my changelog files are located under /src/main/resources/db directory in one of the Maven modules within a project.

Maven profile which runs Liquibase, notice path: db/masterChangeLog.xml

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>*** Install a last major release version of db ***</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <changeLogFile>db/masterChangeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
                                <contexts>dbBuildContext, dmlDevContext</contexts>
                                <propertyFile>db/liquibase-${user.name}.properties</propertyFile>
                                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                                <logging>debug</logging>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```

db/masterChangeLog.xml file includes these files:

```
<include file="db/install.xml"/>
<include file="db/update.xml"/>
```

db/install.xml file includes other changelog files (so does update.xml):

```
<includeAll path="db/install/seq"/>
<includeAll path="db/install/tab"/>
<includeAll path="db/install/cst"/>
<includeAll path="db/latest/vw"  />
```

Spring context executes the same set of db scripts upon app startup as follows:

```
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="baseCostManagementDataSource" />
    <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db/masterChangelog.xml" />
    <property name="contexts" value="dbBuildContext, dmlDevContext" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I've tested a similar configuration with Liquibase 3.0.5 and this doesn't work.

If I run migrations with SpringLiquibase, all my changesets FILENAME column values will be prefixed with "classpath:" whereas no such prefix is prepended when migrations are run via Maven.

Therefore, migrations conflict when using both ways.

Comment: I am bit confused with  <property name="contexts" value="dbBuildContext, dmlDevContext" /> is it not  <property name="contexts" value="test, production" /> ? please clarify.

Comment: Thank you man. Perfect!!!!!
My only difference is:
    <includeAll path="scripts/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

Comment: I'm using Liquibase 3.5.3 and its Maven plugin with the same version and using the same path inside Spring and my pom.xml solves the problem!

Comment: @Rolf This answer now works because of [this PR](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/187) (I think it's yours :-) ). It basically strips `classpath:` prefix before filename comparison, so the fact that FILENAME column values are prefixed with `classpath:` doesn't prevent it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The Maven Plugin has the configuration property changeLogDirectory in recent versions.

Hence setting `<changeLogDirectory>src/main/resources</changeLogDirectory>` should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the logicalFilePath attribute in each databaseChangeLog file. See http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html